# How To Upload Images to Amazon S3 Using Perl?

Tags: amazon-web-services, perl, amazon-s3, upload

I'm trying to upload files to S3 using Perl.

According to this module:

http://metacpan.org/pod/Amazon::S3::Bucket

...the following code will upload text files:

```
# create resource with meta data (attributes)
my $keyname = 'testing.txt';
my $value   = 'T';
$bucket->add_key(
   $keyname, $value,
   {   content_type        => 'text/plain',
       'x-amz-meta-colour' => 'orange',
   }
);
```

However, how do you upload images (GIF, JPEG, PNG) to S3?

Answer (score 11):

That code *won't* upload the file - it's simply setting the value associated with the key "testing.txt" to "T".  If you want to upload a file you could use the [add_key_filename](http://search.cpan.org/~tima/Amazon-S3/lib/Amazon/S3/Bucket.pm#add_key_filename) method:

> The method works like add_key except the value is assumed to be a
>   filename on the local file system. The file will be streamed rather
>   then loaded into memory in one big chunk.

Something like:

```
$bucket->add_key_filename(
    'image-key.jpg',
    'local-filename.jpg',
    {
        content_type => 'image/jpeg',
    }
);
```

Adjust the content type as required.