# How to upload a binary file with Amazon::S3 in Perl?

Tags: perl, amazon-s3

I can't find any examples of how to upload binary files to Amazon S3 with Amazon::S3 library in Perl. All examples are copy/pasted around and just do text/plain uploads almost as if everything was just plain text.

Here's an example from [http://metacpan.org/pod/Amazon::S3](http://metacpan.org/pod/Amazon%3a%3aS3):

```
my $keyname = 'testing.txt';
my $value   = 'T';
$bucket->add_key(
    $keyname, $value,
    {   content_type        => 'text/plain',
        'x-amz-meta-colour' => 'orange',
    }
);
```

This creates a plain text file 'testing.txt' in the Amazon S3 with contents "T". And all the examples on the Internet just copy this example and modify the value "T". I couldn't find a single example that uploads binary data.

How do I upload a image/jpeg with binary contents to Amazon S3?

Comment: Maybe change that content type to 'application/octet-stream'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Upload Images to Amazon S3 Using Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757574/how-to-upload-images-to-amazon-s3-using-perl)

Answer (score 3):

This perl uploads a jpeg file to S3, puts it on reduced redundancy storage, makes it public, and sets its mime type so that it displays correctly in a web browser. Please see the result of the upload at: https://s3.amazonaws.com/AppaApps/z/p.jpg

```
    use warnings FATAL => qw(all);
    use strict;
    use Data::Dump qw(dump);
    use Amazon::S3;

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Constants
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------

    my $s3 = Amazon::S3->new
     ({aws_access_key_id     => "...",
       aws_secret_access_key => "...",
       retry                 => 1
      }
     );

    my $b = $s3->bucket("AppaApps");   # Our bucket
    my $f = "z/p.jpg";                 # A specific file (key) on S3
    my $F = "p.jpg";                   # Local file to upload

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Upload a file
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------

    $b->add_key_filename($f, "p.jpg", 
     {"x-amz-storage-class"=>"REDUCED_REDUNDANCY", 'x-amz-meta-version'=>'12.11.22', acl_short=>'public-read',
      "Content-Type"=>"image/jpeg", 
     });
    print dump($b->errstr), "\n" if $b->errstr;
```

Comment: What is feature :5.16 used for in this example?

Comment: @bodacydo: it must be `say` operator. It is better to avoid depending on it, or at least write it as `use v5.16;` - shorter and to the point

Answer (score 1):

Granted that this would require installation of 3rd party software, but as a workaround, I use s3cmd and system calls in my perl scripts to upload arbitrary data to my buckets.

s3cmd can be found here: http://s3tools.org/s3cmd and once your keys and permissions are set up, it is as easy as calling the following within a perl script. (**Big thanks to Michal Ludvig for making this tool easy to use and free.)

```
`s3cmd put YOUR_FILE s3://YOUR_BUCKET/`;
```

It is a hack, but if you are willing to try an inelegant, but pragmatic, solution this is what I do.